# How should I fix libraries that can't be found because of multiarch naming?

Tags: 64-bit, java, shared-library, multiarch, pcscd

I've run into this problem a few times now. I have some program that is looking for a library and can't find it, even though it is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Maybe this a flaw in the way the dependent program was written. I don't know much about this, but I would expect the dependent program to specify the name of the library, and let the system search a list of paths.

Can anyone explain briefly how Ubuntu expects a properly behaved program to look for dynamic libraries?

As a concrete example, the latest case involves the `libpcsclite.so` library. The Oracle documentation suggests that Java (the dependent program) will look in `/usr/lib64` and `/usr/local/lib64` on my system—neither of which exist. I've had similar problems in the past with non-Java dependents. Part of my question is, why would a program list search locations like this? Is there a search mechanism provided by Linux that should be used instead?

Is this a problem with Java, to be corrected by using its `sun.security.smartcardio.library` system property, or is `pcsclite` failing to support the multi-architecture naming conventions correctly? If the latter, should I be creating symlinks manually, or is this something a tool like `ldconfig` should fix?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is you are installing packages outside of apt (apt-get). Either use Ubuntu packages (ppa if possible) or if you are compiling packages, as you compile, use `./configure --help` and specify a library path as a part of your configuration.

See also:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-a-non-standard-library-path-when-compiling-software-781185/

From the second link:

```
CFLAGS="-I/path/to/your/headers" LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/your/lib" ./configure --blah
```

If you need further assistance you will have to be more specific regarding "some program that is looking for a library and can't find it" - What program? How did you install it ? etc.

To set your java environment, edit `~/.pam_environment`, add:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/<your version of java>
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

For all users (system) edit `/etc/environment`

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables

Comment: Thanks. Actually, in one of these cases, I used `apt` from the command line, and in the example above, I used the Synaptic package manager; all of my pcsc libraries are supported by the distribution and provided by Ubuntu Developers. As for the program, in the latest case, it's Java 1.7.0_05, installed from a tarball from Oracle.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu) or its answers. It deals with the location of Java; I don't have any problems with that. The problem is Java's inability to find another shared library on my system, `libpcsdlite.so`.

Comment: If you set your path, and JAVA from SUN can not find system libs, then it would be a bug with JAVA.

Comment: If it is a problem with an application from the Ubuntu repositories, you should file a bug report with Ubuntu.

Comment: I am looking for more general background, as described in my question. Bugging Oracle wouldn't get me a useful solution, and I already have a work around. What I want to know, is how is this supposed to work, and when it doesn't what's the right way to handle it?